# How to find the source code of getPort defined in a index.d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How can I find the source code of the `getPort()` function defined [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port/blob/main/index.d.ts#L45) :

```
export default function getPort(options?: Options): Promise<number>;
```

I searched through the [repository](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port) but could not find it. Could it be the same as the `getPorts()` function in the [index.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port/blob/0760c987c17581395d4e30432881dcb0ca6ca94a/index.js#L82) file ?

Comment: It's the default export; there's only one...

Comment: Thanks, so it is the `getPorts()` function in `index.js` then? I was confused since the names were different

Comment: Yes. The name for a default export, whether it even has one, doesn't generally matter because the consumer names it on import anyway.